# Loop invariant and using to solve algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, loop-invariant

So if I have the following code:

```
public int sumSquares(int n){
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i = 1; i <=n; i++){
      sum += i*i;
   }
   return sum;
}
```

I must now find a loop invariant. I was told that for a loop like this, an invariant of Y = i^2 is considered a loop invariant, however I don't know if I get how to prove it is a loop invariant. Since Y is just something, then it is always true before, during, and after the loop because it is whatever i*i is... Is that a valid proof of it being an invariant?

Also, when it comes to proving the algorithm with the invariant, is it correct to say that sum = the sum from 1 to n of i*i (or Y, the loop invariant) = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6

Then use induction to show that that is correct? Is that properly using the loop invariant to prove the algorithm?

Would love some help :)

Comment: sum + (Sum j*j, j = i..n) = (Sum j * j, j = 1..n)

Comment: What? I don't believe sum can be in the loop invariant as it is something not constant. and the algorithm is the sum 1 through n of i^2, so that is what sum will equal at the end.

Comment: The whole equasion is always true between iterations.

Comment: To my understanding, `sum` must necessarily be contained in the loop invariant, since the desired condition after termination, which is a statement about `sum`, would be hard to prove.

Answer (score 1):

The invariant should be, at the entrance to the loop, for any `i`,

```
sum = 0 + 1*1 + 2*2 + ... + (i-1)*(i-1)
```

The above claim can be proven by induction. Let `sum` be the variable at the beginning of the loop, and `sum'` the variable at its end, then:

```
sum' = sum + i*i = 0 + 1*1 + ... + i*i
```

This allows you to use the fact that in addiiton, when the loop terminates `i=n+1`, so when the program terminates, you get:

```
sum = 0 + 1*1 + ... + n*n
```

Comment: Isn't that using two invariants with sum and sum'? And I was being told from my TA who did a very similar loop with an a+=i+1 inside the for loop that you couldn't use 'a' in the invariant and that you should use Y= i+1.